# Adding a GFCI to my bathroom light switch

Tags: wiring

I have 2 bathrooms that have no receptacle's at all in them. I'm having to use extension cords that are ran from the bedroom to the bathroom to use any type of power instruments such as a hair dryer, etc. How can I replace the light switch with a GFCI receptacle and light switch, all in one box, to each bathroom?

Comment: Which circuit breakers are they supplied by?  Are any other receptacles upstream (closer to the power supply) than this light?  Are all bathrooms on the same breaker?

Comment: depends on the wiring of the switch box, specifically if there's a neutral behind the box or not. if there is, you can do what you want for a few bucks. if not, you need to rewire before buying receptacles.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes in question?

Comment: Is the light fixture in the ceiling or on the wall above the lavatory? If the fixture is on the wall above the lavatory, you could get a ceramic fixture that would have a receptacle in it. All the white ceramic fixtures I have seen that have a receptacle also have a pull chain switch, but the integrated receptacle is not switched. You would leave the pull chain switch on and use the wall switch.

Comment: See http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Porcelain-Lampholder-with-White-Pull-Chain-and-Grounded-Outlet-18305/203716802?cm_mmc=Shopping%7cTHD%7cG%7c0%7cG-BASE-PLA-D27L-InteriorLighting%7c&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIpsDj8PWx1gIVRrXACh0sIweUEAQYASABEgKnfPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds&dclid=CLmaxv31sdYCFcgoaQod_tYGHQ

Comment: @JimStewart  I'm not finding the GFCI function in your plan or your linked example.

Comment: @Upnorth, I was imagining that the breaker would be replaced with a GFCI breaker. No changes would be required in the wiring.

Comment: @JimStewart Sorry, I was assuming you were still trying to conform your answer to the parameters of the question, i.e., "replace the light switch with a GFCI receptacle, all in one box".  Yes, one may certainly provide branch GFCI protection via the breaker replacement.